# How to display list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, reactjs, object

How correctly to display the list received through URL in JSON?

Here is an example of a [project](https://codesandbox.io/s/Lggwnjj0W). If I use a local variable - everything works, if I get the list, it displays an error.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.urlNews = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1nrbo";
    this.state = {
      news: "",
      links: [
        {
          name: "Имя 1",
          url: "http://localhost:1",
          use: true
        },
        {
          name: "Имя 2",
          url: "http://localhost:2",
          use: false
        },
        {
          name: "Имя 3",
          url: "http://localhost:3",
          use: false
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  getNews() {
    fetch(this.urlNews)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          news: json
        });
        console.log(this.state.news[1]);
      });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getNews();
  }
  render() {
    const { news } = this.state;
    return (
      <ul>
        {news.map((item, index) => <li>1</li>)}
      </ul>
    );
  }
```

How right?

Comment: And what error does it displays? You should always say this when you ask for help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you defined initial value of news as **string**, define it as an array.

Write it like this:

```
this.state = {
   news: [],
   ....
```

fetch will be a asynchronous call and you are fetching in [**componentDidMount**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) that will get called after initial rendering, so before you get the response, you are trying to use map on string and that is throwing the error.

Check this snippet:

```js
let news = '';

news.map(el => {
   console.log(el);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using map properly. map does not support object literal. Need to supply it with an array. You need to define the sate as an array and use the following render function.

```
this.state = {
  news: [],
  links: [
    {
      name: "Имя 1",
      url: "http://localhost:1",
      use: true
    },
    {
      name: "Имя 2",
      url: "http://localhost:2",
      use: false
    },
    {
      name: "Имя 3",
      url: "http://localhost:3",
      use: false
    }
  ]
};
```

The following render function works.

```
 render() {
return (
  <ul>
    {this.state.news.map(() => <li>1</li>)}
  </ul>
);
```

}